# Drag and Drop in Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to automate the functionality of drag and drop using selenium webdriver with java.

I tried:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.dragAndDrop(Sourcelocator, Destinationlocator).build().perform();
```

But nothing happened

Can anybody help?

HTML5 is used

HTML Code of the section

```
<div id="scroll" class="sort-list-wrap" style="height:450px">
<ul id="questiondiv" class="connected-sort ullist ui-sortable" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:450px">
<li id="id_365">
<li id="id_356">
<li id="id_355">
<li id="id_354">
<li id="id_353">
<li id="id_352">
</ul>
</div>
<div id="loading" class="loading-text" style="display: none;">
<img src="/Images/loader-small.gif" alt="loader-small">
Loading questions..
</div>
<div id="loadmore" class="btn-wrap text-center" style="height: 42px;">
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary purple" onclick="loadMore();">Load more</a>
</div>

<div class="as-cell qd-arrow">
<i class="icon-sort-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="as-cell">
<div class="panel v3-panel">
<div class="panel-header table-header has-border">
<div class="ph-title">
<h2>Selected Questions</h2>
<p>Reorder the selected questions in this section.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<h2 class="qstn-title">
<strong id="quescount_lbl">0 / 5</strong>
questions selected
</h2>
<div id="questiondropdiv" class="sort-list-wrap mCustomScrollbar1" style="overflow: hidden;">
<ul id="secondList" class="connected-sort ullist ui-sortable" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:550px"> </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and Code?

Comment: It does not work if it is HTML5. check https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604.

Comment: @GirishBellamkonda : HTML code is added

Comment: @vins : HTML5 is used in the application. How can we perform drag and drop in HTML5?